# Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error when I run my tests with Selenium using chromedriver.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248316,platform=Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86)
```

I did download google-chrome stable and also chromedriver and have used this code to start the browser.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

Any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 44):

**For Linux :**

Start the **Display** before start the Chrome. for more info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187952/2336184)

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: hi, can you explain why is pyvirtualdisplay needed?

Comment: One need to run the commands    >> "pip install pyvirtualdisplay"      and  >> "sudo apt-get install xvfb"

Comment: What does the visible flag do? I cannot see any display with or without specifying it

Comment: A great solution! I ran my driver with the option --headless, which suddenly stopped being an option and caused errors and distress. This solved the issue right up. 

@vikramvi note about installing xvfb was also helpfull. Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

To help debug this problem you can use the `service_log_path` and `service_args` arguments to the selenium webdriver to see output from the chromedriver:

```
service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format(outputdir)
service_args = ['--verbose']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver',
        service_args=service_args,
        service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

I was getting this same exception message and found two ways to get past it; I'm not sure if the OP's problem is the same, but if not, the chromedriver log will hopefully help. Looking at my log, I discovered that the chromedriver (I tried 2.9 down to 2.6 while trying to fix this problem) decides which browser to run in a very unexpected way. In the directory where my chromedriver is located I have these files:

```
$ ls -l /path/to/
-rwx------  1 pjh grad_cs 5503600 Feb  3 00:07 chromedriver-2.9
drwxr-xr-x  3 pjh grad_cs    4096 Mar 28 15:51 chromium
```

When I invoke the chromedriver using the same python code as the OP:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver-2.9')
```

This leads to the exception message. In the chromedriver.log I found this message:

```
[1.043][INFO]: Launching chrome: /path/to/chromium ...
```

Unbelievable! The chromedriver is trying to use `/path/to/chromium` (which is not an executable file, but a directory containing source code) as the browser to execute! Apparently chromedriver tries to search the current directory for a browser to run before searching my `PATH`. So, one easy solution to this problem is to check the directory where the `chromedriver` is located for files/directories like `chrome` and `chromium` and move them to a different directory than the `chromedriver`.

A better solution is to explicitly tell selenium / chromedriver which browser to execute by using the chrome_options argument:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome'
service_log_path = "{}/chromedriver.log".format(outputdir)
service_args = ['--verbose']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver',
        chrome_options=options,
        service_args=service_args,
        service_log_path=service_log_path)
```

The chromedriver.log now shows:

```
[0.999][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome ...
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks man. But I already did figure out a way. It happens that by just changing from `driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')` to `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, I was able to make my code run. I don't know why that happened, but it just did! @pjhuw

Comment: thanks for showing how to output to the chromedriver.log. really useful

Comment: Thanks for providing way to find the logs of chrome driver. It helped me to find the issue.

Comment: Another reason - I was running as root without --no-sandbox switch and chrome did not like it. Switched to another user and voila.

Comment: OMG. This worked for me. You're a saviour.

Answer (score 28):

An alternative solution of using a virtual display is the headless mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thank you. After hours of searching this is the only solution that works. You made my day.

Comment: 4 years later...THANK YOU!

Answer (score 13):

If using Linux make sure you are not running as root. That what gave me the error.

Comment: If you're using a CI tool, you might be running as root without realizing it (or having control over it). I unfortunately had to use `--no-sandbox` to get it working.

Comment: Wowwwwww, it worked for me, but anybody knows the reason?

Comment: GuySoft, hi, I try all that i see in stackoverflow, but do not solved error. How can I change run other user? without root.

Comment: @TornikeKharitonishvili Your python script should run as another user, for example you could dertamine the user for ID 1000, which in a single-user system tends to be the default one``sudo -u $(awk -F':' -v uid=1000 '$3 == uid { print $1 }' /etc/passwd) python3 ./script.py ``

Answer (score 7):

Someone already mentioned about `--no-sandbox` option, but to expand on it: make sure, it's the first option you pass:

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                Paths.get("setups", driverFolder, driverFile).toAbsolutePath().toString());

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "English");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        options.addArguments("enable-automation");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);

        options.addArguments("enable-features=NetworkServiceInProcess");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(15, SECONDS);
```

When it was added after other options, I got the error.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to fix this issue by making sure your version of chromedriver is right for the version of Chrome you have installed, which you can check [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). You will also need to remove your current version of chromedriver before installing the new one, as described in [Delete Chromedriver from Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570005/delete-chromedriver-from-ubuntu)

Comment: I spent a good day on this. In the end it was a simple version mismatch!

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved using below steps

1. Install Xvfb
   **Centos 7** : `yum install chromedriver chromium xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`
2. update chrome driver
   **Centos 7** : `wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip`

Comment: for Xvfb centos installation, pls check https://reiners.io/installing-xvfb-in-centos/

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same  issue and fixed it by installing Chrome in:

```
C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
```

You can do this by running the Chrome Setup and saying no when prompted by the User Account Control.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I crawl something using scrapy + selenium + chrome driver on `Centos 7`，and  the method of following url solved my problem.

```
yum install mesa-libOSMesa-devel gnu-free-sans-fonts
```

refer:https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=695212

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for selenium webdriver is X virtual frame buffer:

```
with Xvfb() as _:
    timeout_request = ConfigTargetsManager.target_global_configs.get('timeout_request', 10)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ConfigTargetsManager.target_global_configs.get('chrome_browser_path',
                                                                                             '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'))
    driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04.
May be useful for someone.
I got this bug when trying to get selenium to work with a version of Brave (Deb) installed from the brave.com repository.

Additionally installed Brave from the snap image, added it:

```
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9224')
options.binary_location = '/snap/bin/brave'
```

This solved the problem.