# Try to start chrome driver on linux with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to find answer and can't, now I ask by myself.

I wrote simple test

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/tranter/workspace/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.close()
```

than I have traceback

```
> tranter@tranter-VirtualBox:~/workspace$ python testchrome.py Traceback
> (most recent call last): File "testchrome.py", line 6, in <module>
> driver =
> webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/tranter/workspace/chromedriver")
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 65, in __init__ keep_alive=True) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 73, in __init__ self.start_session(desired_capabilities,
> browser_profile) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 121, in start_session 'desiredCapabilities':
> desired_capabilities, File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
> line 173, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
> line 166, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen,
> stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
> u'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n (Driver
> info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Linux 3.13.0-35-generic x86)'
```

I have latest version of `chromedriver` 10, latest `chromium`, latest `selenium webdriver`.
And it all I start in xubuntu

> Linux version 3.13.0-35-generic (buildd@roseapple) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 15 01:58:01 UTC 2014

Please help me :(

Answer (score 15):

**For Linux user:**
   Start the **Display** before start the Chrome. for more info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364290/2336184)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
# Add following 2 line before start the Chrome
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))  
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
display.stop()
```

Comment: why all the upvotes for an answer that is totally unrelated to the question?

Answer (score 0):

`2.10.267517` is not the latest version.

```
$ chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 2.10.267518
```

With above version, Python 2.7.6, your code work well. (except that I modified the chromedriver path)

FYI, here are uname for my ubuntu:

```
$ uname -a
Linux jmlee12 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

Comment: @tranter, Here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html  You can find the current lastest version here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.10/

Comment: I try here, but 10 verion is 17, not 18. And it is 32bit version, can you share me this thing somehow?

Comment: @tranter, If you follow the link, you can find both 32bit, 64bit version. FYI, here's the link to the 64bit version (2.10.267518) http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.10/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: I don't understand why when I download the chromedriver_linux32.zip 2014-05-01 20:46:22 2.33MB 

4fecc99b066cb1a346035bf022607104 it's gonna be 17 version :(

Comment: @tranter, Do you mean your system is 32bit?