# Cannot get selenium-webdriver running under Raspbian using Python and geckodriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspbian, geckodriver

I am trying to get selenium running in headless mode on a raspberry pi. My scripts work perfectly fine on my Windows machine, but I just cannot get this particular combination working:

- Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
- Python 3.7.3
- geckodriver 0.23.0 ( 2018-10-04)
- selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59
- Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0

first I launch `selenium-server-standalone` as described in the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#running-standalone-selenium-server-for-use-with-remotedrivers):

```sh
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar &
[1] 1842
14:39:26.881 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
14:39:27.321 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2019-06-30 14:39:27.589:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2114ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:39:28.755 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
14:39:29.174 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Then I run following test script in Python:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 800))
display.start()

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

And I get the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug3.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection refused
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975241/try-to-start-chrome-driver-on-linux-with-selenium-webdriver) thread, I included `pyvirtualdisplay`. But there is not much difference in the outcome. Also the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753393/how-to-make-firefox-headless-programmatically-in-selenium-with-python) thread does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the problem, which was a combination of three mistakes:

1. There is no need to run selenium-server-standalone
2. I wasn't using the right version of geckodriver, raspbian does not have to most recent build of Firefox/Iceweasel. The correct version for Mozilla 52 is geckodriver 0.17 The list of compatible versions is [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html) and the releases of geckodriver are [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
3. xvfb / pyvirtualdisplay is not necessary

Comment: why are you using pyvirtualdisplay if you are running headless mode?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment?

Comment: headless is a mode of the browser that does not require a virtual display like xvfb provides.

Comment: 
have to do more tests then