# Jenkins can't launch real browser on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I've selenium script which launches chrome browser, goes to a website and does basic checks.

When I tried running same script locally through jenkins I got error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.13.0-17-generic x86_64)
```

This is resolved by [Unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424737/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally/28188009#comment82398274_28188009)

I'm confused why **Jenkins** can't launch **real chrome browser** on **Ubuntu** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Jenkins server normally does not have a graphical subsystem installed in the operating system. When a real browser (or any app) tries to create a window that fails.

You will need to run your tests on Jenkins using a headless browser - one that does not need a graphical subsystem. Chrome-headless is currently the preferred option, replacing the now abandoned PhantomJS.

Comment: can you please have a look at one one jenkins related query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671536/jenkins-job-throwing-error-importerror-no-module-named-selenium-even-though