# Selenium Crashes on Chrome Start

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make selenium open a user profile so i can automate stuff in my google accounts without having to login every time, with the code below i have managed to open chrome but as soon as it opens, it crashes, here's my code. (My OS is MacOS Ventura)

My `chromdriver` and my Google Chrome are in the same version

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")


ch_options = Options()  # options
ch_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/Users/matheus/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
ch_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 2")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=ch_options)

driver.get("https://gmail.com")
```

Here's the crash log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=ch_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 272, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 364, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/matheus/dev/work-automations/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
0   chromedriver                        0x000000010276aa88 chromedriver + 4123272
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001026f6778 chromedriver + 3647352
2   chromedriver                        0x00000001023b8ac4 chromedriver + 248516
3   chromedriver                        0x00000001023dc2a4 chromedriver + 393892
4   chromedriver                        0x00000001023d8858 chromedriver + 378968
5   chromedriver                        0x00000001024125a0 chromedriver + 615840
6   chromedriver                        0x00000001024121d8 chromedriver + 614872
7   chromedriver                        0x00000001023e2b10 chromedriver + 420624
8   chromedriver                        0x00000001023e3c30 chromedriver + 425008
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010273cae4 chromedriver + 3934948
10  chromedriver                        0x000000010273ff24 chromedriver + 3948324
11  chromedriver                        0x0000000102740508 chromedriver + 3949832
12  chromedriver                        0x0000000102746b30 chromedriver + 3975984
13  chromedriver                        0x0000000102740b24 chromedriver + 3951396
14  chromedriver                        0x000000010271b71c chromedriver + 3798812
15  chromedriver                        0x000000010275d2f0 chromedriver + 4068080
16  chromedriver                        0x000000010275d444 chromedriver + 4068420
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000102771450 chromedriver + 4150352
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018421a06c _pthread_start + 148
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000184214e2c thread_start + 8


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is your version of `chromedriver` the same version as Chrome?

Comment: Yes, i updated my chrome to version 107 before starting this project and downloaded compatible chromedriver

Comment: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe finish line so

Comment: MacOS does not support .exe files, if i remove the profile settings it works just fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424737/unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnormally

Comment: also check out[webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Answer (score 1):

The path provided for Profile 2 seems to be the original one located in library.

If your browser is open at the same time it can cause conflicts.
I recommend to make a copy of the original folder and use it instead.

In case you don't know how to access it:

> Finder > Go > Press Option Key (Library appears) > Library > Application Support > Google > Chrome > Profile 2

So I have modified your code, and it should look like this :
I let you change the path according to where you will place your Profile copy.

```
from selenium import webdriver

ch_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ch_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/matheus/desktop/Selenium Profile/Profile 2")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=ch_options)
driver.get("https://gmail.com")
```

Hope this helps you,
Best