# Unable to use chromedriver on linux server [Exec format error]

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I have a raspberry-pi running linux-server as platform. Therefore there is no GUI and I execute all my tasks through terminal by SSH-ing into the Pi. Platform details:

```
uname -a

>> Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1080-raspi #91-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Jan 19 09:35:03 UTC 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

### **Chromium [No issues here]**

I have installed Chromium through snap.

```
chromium --version
>> Chromium 109.0.5414.119 snap
```

I am able to run chromium, navigate to a website, and take a snapshot

```
chromium --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.wikipedia.com

>> 0215/140750.965255:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0215/140752.998408:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(385)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0215/140802.665622:INFO:headless_shell.cc(223)] 84646 bytes written to file screenshot.png
```

### **Chromedriver [Issues]**

I downloaded chromedriver this way

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.37/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

And moved Chromedriver to the applications folder after unzipping

I get this error when trying to get chromedriver version, let alone run it

```
chromedriver --version
>> bash: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

### My Python Script [Issues]

Here is the script I want to be able to run finally

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.com")
driver.save_screenshot("proof.png")
```

This is the error I get when I try to run it

```
python3 test.py

>> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 'chromedriver'
```

## What I've Tried already

#### Using chromedriver directly through ChromeDriverManager

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(path=".", chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.com")
driver.save_screenshot("proof.png")
```

The error

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/109.0.5414/chromedriver'
```

#### Checking file permissions

Made sure file has execute permissions

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

>> -rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 20427216 Sep  8  2021 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: Your `chromedriver` is likely compiled for `x86_64` architecture. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver`?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I don't know why I didn't start with this. It helped. Spent another few hours tacking a resulting problem I was able to address using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735763/10057842

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you are having a raspberry-pi running linux-server as platform with *Chromium 109.0.5414.119* you need to use [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) of:

- [Version ***109.0***](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=109.0.5414.74/)
- Linux compatible format i.e. *`chromedriver_linux64.tar.gz`*

Your effective line of code will be:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.tar.gz
```

Comment: This was basically it. I followed alexeyR's solution from the comments which essentially handles the `chromuim-browser` and `chromedriver` installs at the same time. Thanks!